# Why google chrome does not write cookie with a special name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, setcookie

I was testing some codes and write a cookie on my machine (MVC 5, .net 4.7), my test cookie name is "test".

After a while google chrome (Version 63.0.3239.84) did not write my cookie with the name "test" anymore but if I change the cookie name, it works fine as before.

I clear all the cookies but I can not write a cookie with this name: "test".

I clear chrome cookies files at:

> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

But I still have the same problem.

My code:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("test", "1");
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Comment: How do you determine Chrome doesn't write the cookie?

Comment: Right click on my page> Inspect>Application>Storage>Cookies

Comment: Other users of the site are editing your question: Keep it simple. Don't add noise, or anything that doesn't explain your point. Don't call out other users, just simply **clarify** your question, adding detail. A question will only be closed if it reaches 5 votes.

Comment: Also: No one can delete comments, except for moderators or if they're flagged by multiple* people. Keep it constructive; stick to explaining why it shouldn't be closed, or ask him for clarification to his comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From chrome v63 the cookies location was changed
chrome://settings/siteData
remove from here first then try.

Comment: so... did it work or not?

Comment: @motevalizadeh the question is _"Why aren't my cookies written"_, not _"Where does Chrome 63 store cookie data"_. This is a debugging hint, not an answer to the question, so it should not be posted as such. See also [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). And no, I cannot delete other people's comments.